# vanilla bootstrap: 12 columns go beyond the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With vanilla bootstrap, I sometimes run into the issue where 12 columns go beyond the full width, so I end up having 1 fewer column. I have solved the issue from time to time without understanding why exactly I ran into the issue. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Have you set your container to be 100% wide? If not can we see the code you're using?

Comment: I do not have any custom css files. I just included https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you are using container-fluid, you also need to use row-fluid too, see if that works and stops the columns from misbehaving. Plus you have twon containers where as one should be fine with multiple rows.

Comment: Using row-fluid does not fix the problem unfortunately. Also, I believe in the latest version it's okay to use `.row` under `.container-fluid`...